# SQL BigQuery - Error that variable is not grouped by even though it is

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

SQL Code:

```
 SELECT community_table.community_name,
        community_table.id,
        DATE(timestamp) as date,
        ifnull(COUNT(distinct app_opened.user_id), 0) as num_opened_DAU,
        lag(COUNT(distinct app_opened.user_id)) OVER 
        (ORDER BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, DATE(timestamp)) as pre_Value
        
        FROM *** app_opened

        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT id, community_id_2, context_traits_first_name, context_traits_last_name
          FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM ***,
                UNNEST (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(context_traits_community_ids, "$")) as community_id_2
               ) 
          GROUP by community_id_2, id, context_traits_first_name, context_traits_last_name) as community_id_table
        ON community_id_table.id = app_opened.user_id

        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT id, name as community_name
          FROM ***) as community_table
        ON TO_JSON_STRING(community_table.id) = community_id_table.community_id_2

        WHERE app_opened.user_id is not null AND 
              EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE(timestamp)) = 2 AND
              community_table.community_name is not null
        GROUP BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, DATE(timestamp)
```

Error Message:
[image]

I am quite confused on what could be going wrong here, as the error says that timestamp is not grouped, even though I have grouped it at the bottom. I tried including just timestamp rather than Date(timestamp), but that ruins the table data that I am trying to create, where I find the number of users on a single day. Does anyone have any other ideas? My goal is for a single row, get the previous row's data, but because I am grouping by specific metrics, I need to make sure they are ordered by them as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should put the query in the question as *text* so there is some hope of others being able to read it.

Comment: @Gordon Just edited! Sorry new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply need to modify `OVER` part as:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, DATE(timestamp)) as pre_Value
```

UPDATE. Seems that the problem was caused by using `DATE()` function within `OVER` so it can be solved by using `DATE(timestamp)` inside of subquery and passing alias to `OVER`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work because the OVER part requires an ORDER BY clause, and even if I add this PARTITION BY clause to the beginning, it still gives me the issue that timestamp is not grouped or aggregated by

Comment: @EricSingh Oh, actually sorry for confusion about GROUP BY at the end of query, it should be there since you're using aggregation `count()`. I removed that part from my answer. By the way have you tried using both `partition by` and `order by` inside of `OVER` ?

Comment: No worries, thanks! I did try using both the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` inside of `OVER`, but then it still gives the error that timestamp needs to be grouped or aggregrated, but the timestamp it refers to this time is the one inside of the PARTITION BY.

Comment: @EricSingh how about removing `DATE()` keyword? `OVER (PARTITION BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, timestamp ORDER BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, timestamp)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So removing `DATE()` does make the Query valid, but it does not give me the table that I want. Without `DATE()`, `timestamp` currently shows something like `2020-08-15 08:29:32.229 UTC`, but with `DATE(timestamp)` it just shows `2020-08-15`, which is what I want. If I remove it, the table gets messed up and no longer counts the number of active users that appear on the certain date, but rather that second which isn't too helpful.

Comment: @EricSingh ah, in that case it probably makes sense to use `DATE()` in subquery (i.e. `DATE(timestamp) as dt`), and then use `dt` inside of `OVER`

Comment: So I try to include that in the query like so `SELECT community_table.community_name,
        community_table.id,
        DATE(timestamp) as date,
        ifnull(COUNT(distinct app_opened.user_id), 0) as num_opened_DAU,
        lag(COUNT(distinct app_opened.user_id)) OVER 
        (ORDER BY community_table.community_name, community_table.id, date) as pre_Value` and also then group by date as well, but it gives me the error that date is an unrecognized name. Are you suggesting that I do another query on top of this? Thanks!

Comment: @EricSingh no, I mean getting it from subquery. `timestamp` is coming from the table `app_opened`, right? so instead of using `FROM app_opened`, you should use `FROM (select DATE(timestamp) as dt, ..., ..., FROM app_opened) t`

Comment: This solution worked! Thank you so much, appreciate it!